# How to get concrete element from ListModel in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

How to pick any item in list model?
It's not looks like as in C++

```
    ListModel {
        id: fruitModel
    }
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: fruitModel
        delegate: Component {
            Text { text: name }
        }
    }
 function AddAndGet() {
    fruitModel.append({"name":"Jackfruit"});
    How to get element on index from ListModel?
    // console.log(fruitModel[0].name);  
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [ListModel.get(index)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#get-method)?

Comment: but how set width or height from this element?

Comment: set it from within the Component

Comment: Didn't you see it in the docs? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#get-method. I.e. `console.log(fruitModel.get(0).name);`.